# How can I add a tabindex attribute to an nvd3 pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, nvd3.js

I have a basic pie chart with 3 wedges. When you click on a wedge of the pie, a tooltip will display. My intent is to have the same functionality for a keydown event.

Scenario: When a pie slice has focus, a user can hit a key (ex: enter) which will display the tooltip exactly how the click event does.

I figured this will require 2 steps.

1. Make each pie wedge (.nv-slice) focusable by adding a 'tabindex = 0' attribute
2. Add an event listener that triggers the tooltip similar to how a click event does.

Here is the plunkr that shows the described behavior:
http://plnkr.co/edit/7WkFK2LqzDyDmnIt2xlf?p=preview
(thanks to  @ThanasisGrammatopoulos)

First things first, how can I add a tabindex attribute to each pie wedge? When I try the following code it does not seem to appear:

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-slice').setAttribute("tabindex", "0");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,

The function `setAttribute` is a vanila javascript, so it has to be used on a real javascript html element.

You have 2 options,

**Solution 1**

Get the javascript html element, using the function `each` and then
getting it from `this`.

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-slice').each(function(){
    this.setAttribute("tabindex", "0");
});
```

**Solution 2**

Or as we know from jQuery (a vary polular library library) you can try to see if the equivalent function of the `setAttribute` exist, this function is `attr`.

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-slice').attr("tabindex", "0");
```

Of course all that inside the callback function.

Comment: Ah, I needed the .each()  function! In order to add an 'enter' keydown would I add an event listener in the same  manner the on click function is called?