# How can I use a keyboard listener to trigger a tooltip when called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

I have a simple [pie chart](http://plnkr.co/edit/N1G120ct2zI4agzkyuHI?p=preview). When you click on a pie wedge, a tooltip for that wedge displays.

I'm trying to implement the SAME functionality, but on div elements OUTSIDE of the pie chart.

**Scenario:**

1. User who is focused on the 'Cat 1' div and hits enter displays the tooltip for the Cat 1 wedge
2. User who is focused on the 'Cat 2' div and hits enter displays the tooltip for the Cat 2 wedge
3. User who is focused on the 'Cat 3' div and hits enter displays the tooltip for the Cat 3 wedge

I have tried something along the lines of:

```
function ShowTooltip() {
    d3.selectAll('.nvtooltip').each(function(){
        this.style.setProperty('display', 'block', 'important');
    });
};
```

But if you see in the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N1G120ct2zI4agzkyuHI?p=preview), that doesn't trigger anything. How can I make these dives trigger it's corresponding tooltip?

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    // Capture only if enter key is pressed and .myDiv has focus
    if (event.keyCode === 13 && $('.cat-count').is(':focus')) {
        console.log('do something');
        ShowTooltip();
    }   
});
```

Comment: important doesn't really work in jquery - well i've found it difficult to set

Comment: How does one "focus" on the 'Cat 1' div, those don't take focus.  Do you mean mouse-overed?

Comment: When you add a tabindex=o attribute to each div, they can receive focus by tabbing to each element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to trigger the corresponding events of pie section when we click on a button in order to show the tooltip.

Check out my Plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/GP9h6eEe4DE8MM9jXolc?p=preview (using Buttons)
http://plnkr.co/edit/MM5nvJ?p=preview (Using Div Elements)

```
        function TriggerEvent(eventName, pieSection, clientX, clientY) {
            var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
            // possible values for eventName for our example are mouseover,mouseout
            event.initMouseEvent(eventName, true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, clientX, clientY);
            pieSection.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
```

On Button Click call the above function:

```
TriggerEvent("mouseover", pieSection.node(), offset.left, offset.top);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking to trigger a keyboard event on a div to call the tooltip, see the original post!

Comment: This example is implemented using <Div> as u wanted instead of buttons.
Checkout this: http://plnkr.co/edit/MM5nvJ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, it worked, please add your latest plunker to the answer link and I will vote this answer!

Comment: added both the links 1.using buttons 2. Using Div Elements

Comment: it appears when I try copying this to my local machine, i get a few errors. offset returns as undefined as well as piesections. Any idea why that is? Is there something that needs to be declared outside the plunk?

Comment: Just make sure that ur code has all the pie sections in a variable like "var pieSections = d3.select("#svgElement").selectAll(".nv-slice")[0];" and offset also we will be calculating using  "offset = $(pieSections[pieSectionIndex]).offset()";

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the listener of the `keydown` event to the element you want:

```
$('.myDiv').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log('do something');
        ShowTooltip();
    }   
});
```

Or you use your approach and check if the `activeElement` is your desired one:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    // Capture only if enter key is pressed and .myDiv has focus
    if (event.keyCode === 13 && $(document.activeElement).is('.myDiv')) {
        console.log('do something');
        ShowTooltip();
    }   
});
```

---

**EDIT**
To display the toolbox, you need to manipulate the CSS properties which hide the toolbox element. These are: `display: none;` and `opacity: 0`. You can do this with jQuery:

```
$('.toolbox').css('opacity', 1).css('display', 'block');
```

However, I would advise against such a manipulation of a D3 toolbox with jQuery. Take a look at the docs of D3 and find out how to display a toolbox programmatically. Here are the changes in a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qNQfdpCMWXOypSqczXXi?p=preview

Comment: This is similar to what I have tried as seen in the original post, the setup is plausible, but it still does not trigger a tooltip

Comment: The `ShowTooltip()` function had an error too. See my updated answer.

Comment: It appears it's still not opening the tooltip, the function does fire as is indicated by the console log

Comment: Open the tooltip first manually, it isn't created in the beginning. But as mentioned above, use the D3 API instead of jQuery to display the tooltip.

Comment: Thanks, but Im looking for this to toggle between tooltips automatically! I cannot manually open the tooltip first because i have to account for users that are strictly keyboard dependant